# Can you hide the status bar in an iOS 7 web app?

Tags: html, iphone-web-app

I'm making an "add to home screen" game, and I want to be able to have the status bar with the time and battery be completely hidden. I know that you can change the color of the status bar; can you completely hide it?

Thank You,

Noah

EDIT:

I don't think I made this clear:
I am not talking about the browser, I'm talking about the add to home screen button.

Comment: Is it different from a normal iPhone app?

Comment: @Dinesh : Yes, in iOS, you can actually save webapps to homescreen if those features are enabled and when you save a website to homescreen, an icon will appear just like a native application and clicking on it triggers the website, but the browser portion will not be shown and if the webapp is designed nice, it will be having the look and feel of a native app..

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this out?

> <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">

See details at: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW4

Answer (score 0):

You can't completely hide it. But what you can do is do a clever script using `window.scrollTo(0,1)` once the page has loaded so users will think that the status bar doesn't exist or make the color transparent. I don't think apple will ever let webapps hide the status bar the reason i think: because they want the users go to top of the page easily and also to check their battery, signal and so on...